# Clicking the back button and landing on a page with a timeout redirect to the same page

Tags: javascript

I have a page with some products that when their link is clicked the next page is a "You're leaving the website to go there" type of page which uses javascript to redirect to the final destination after a setTimeout.

However if the user clicks the back button they he goes back to the "You're leaving the website to go there" page and ocourse gets redirected again to the same page he was before clicking the back button.

How can I escape this loop?

The javascript that makes the final redirection with the timeout is this

```
   function doGoal(url) {
   /*small delay to allow for analytics scripts to send their tracking pixel*/
   setTimeout('document.location = "' + url + '"', 1000)
   }
```

Comment: The problem is that you are redirecting your users per JavaScript. Why are you doing this?

Comment: let's assume I wasn't redirecting with javascript but with php, how would I go about to escape the redirection loop?

Comment: That sounds a lot better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the javascript redirect and added a meta refresh + a link to the final page in case the redirect fails, and all is well